# ArcMap crashes when opening extension folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst

I need to activate the Spatial Analyst extension, however each time I select "extension" ArcMap 10.3.1 crashes.

This is what I'm doing: while in ArcMap, I navigate to Customize/extension then the program crashes, everything single time. I can access the extension folder through ArcCatalog, but that is obviously not what I need.

Has this happen to anyone?

Comment: Every time you have a crash issue you should always first try repair and then reinstall of the software.  Persistent issues should be addressed with Esri Tech Support.

Comment: @Vince Yes, I've already exhausted all three of those suggestions.

Comment: @Vince that seems like a pretty drastic first step, and not everyone has admin rights on their PC, or an IT department responsive enough, to try those things before trying workarounds. Not to mention that an uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS plus reinstalling any patches, addons, etc. can take an hour or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try enabling it via the Python window (under Geoprocessing > Python). Open a Python window and enter:

`arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial")`

That will tell you if a Spatial Analyst license is available. If it is, enter the the command:

`arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")`

That will check out the license and you'll be able to use the Spatial Analyst tools. When you're done, you may want to release the SA license so someone else can use it, you can do that with this command:

`arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")`

Closing ArcMap will also release the license.

Comment: enabling via Python window worked!